# Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError in VScode but no other editors

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-import

This error occurs in VS code for `pip installed modules`.

`Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError`

It was working on all previous days.
I believe that i may have deleted a *.pyc file or something to this extent.

If i do `pip freeze` i can see the module.
For example `import tweepy` could not be resolved, but i can see that it exists in pip freeze `tweepy==3.10.0` and i can see with `python --version` that i have the correct version `Python 3.9.0`.

If i run the same on IDLE (`python3.9`) the code works, which leads me to believe that this is a VScode issue, but i cannot tell what this is or how to fix it.

In fact, if i recreate new folders in VS code, the imports work too.

So the quesiton is, how can i identify where (which folder or file) the corruption is or what has caused VS code to break in this way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution (which **works**) is to recreate all the folders and subfolders.

It is also noted that this is not specific to `python` as seen here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10391

There is also a suggestion here (which is close, but did not resolve the issue):

[vscode import error for python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520127/vscode-import-error-for-python-module).

> *I have noticed that if I use File -> Close folder and then File -> Open Folder... and open the project folder again, the errors are
> gone.*

Comment: As there are no other suggestions and this resolves the issue, i have marked this as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

VStudio may be using a different python interpreter. Just click here and select the proper one:[image]

[image]